# p5.js sound and keyTyped or keyPressed function

Tags: javascript, key, p5.js, audio-player

I’m trying to write a code where when I press a certain keyboard key, a sound will play. I’m using p5.js and have tried the `keyTyped()` function and `keyPressed()` function but it’s not working.
By not working, I meant there is nothing wrong with the code that I’ve typed because it can be played but no sound is produced when i click on the A key.
The code I used
Function keyTyped () {

```
if ( key === ‘a’) {

keyA.play ( ) }

}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. What's `keyA`?

Answer (score 1):

The following works on my system.  Make sure that you have a folder called 'assets' and that you have dragNdropped a file called 'keyA.mp3' into it. I used a Chrome browser on a Mac. Important: click on the gray window first, then type 'a' from your keyboard and it should work.

```
function preload(){
  sound = loadSound('assets/keyA.mp3');
}

function draw() {
createCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight);
background(209);
}

function keyTyped() {
  if (key == 'a') {
    sound.play();
  } 
}
```